# Why is Join Data missing options?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

Why are the options in Join Data missing for me?

[image]

The middle part of the table is missing compared to the one here:

https://community.esri.com/thread/188841-join-data-from-another-layer-based-on-spatial-location

Comment: Something is definitely awry with your install of ArcGIS. I seem to remember a problem similar and I think the answer was a complete reinstall of ArcGIS. You could try deleting your normal.mxt (or renaming, just in case that *wasn't* the problem).

Comment: That's painful. I hope that I don't have to reinstall it.

Comment: It is drastic but I vaguely remember that was the only thing that worked, be sure you **completely uninstall** using one of the Esri Uninsall tools.. But first you could try the Spatial Join tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000 which should have the same options if this is the only dialog box that's being surly. Could you add an ArcGIS desktop tag to your question please, tags are used to filter questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Resetting your ArcGIS application profile:When ArcGIS applications fail, or are behaving strangely, one of the first things to try is to reset your application template document (ArcMap's is "Normal.mxt") or the entire ArcGIS application profile. This resolves many problems with ArcGIS software.

It's a good idea to do this as a every few months, or whenever a service pack or update is applied to ArcGIS, as these template files can gradually fill with cruft and slow down your ArcGIS Desktop applications.

These steps do not require elevated privileges / admin access, as all users own their personal %APPDATA% folder.

The following is adapted from

KB 32797: Error: ArcMap.exe has encountered an error and needs to close

1. Close all ArcGIS Desktop applications.
   This may include killing any lurking "headless" ArcMap.exe, ArcCatalog.exe processes using the Task Manager.
2. Start Windows Explorer and open your application profile folder.
   The location of the user profile depends on the operating system. This folder is normally hidden.

XP/2003/2000: C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\ESRI
Vista/7/2008/8/2012: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI
The easiest way to get there is to simply type the environment variable %APPDATA% (with the percents) into the Windows Explorer path box, which will take you directly to the folder that contains the application profile folder ESRI, regardless of Windows version, and whether hidden files and folders are turned on or not.

3. Browse within the ESRI folder for the application that has the issue
   Each component of the software has a template that stores settings and customizations for that part of ArcGIS. These are:

ArcCatalog: ESRI\DesktopXX.X\ArcCatalog\Normal.gxt
ArcMap: ESRI\DesktopXX.X\ArcMap\Templates\Normal.mxt
ArcToolbox window: ESRI\DesktopXX.X\ArcToolbox.dat

4. Rename the template file (for example, Normal.mxt -> Normal_old.mxt).
   When that component of ArcGIS is started again, a new, fresh template is created. Note that some your customizations (buttons, file connections) may have to be re-applied. This may be all you need to do.
5. Doing a complete application profile reset
   Sometimes it may be advisable to entirely reset the entire user profile:

Close all ArcGIS applications
Rename the %APPDATA%\ESRI folder to another name, for example, ESRI-old
Restart ArcGIS

Some files and folders may be copied over from ESRI-old back to the ESRI folder if you are sure they aren't part of your problem you are trying to fix. Key candidates to copy back are items are personal style files in the ArcMap folder, ArcCatalog.gx and ArcCatalog.gxt (these hold folder connection), and toolboxes in the ArcToolbox folder.